# How to play an audio from content://Media

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play an audio which format is: content://media/external/audio/media/1234

The above path is coming from a database which I saved earlier using audio picker.

I'm using the following code, which is not working:

```
    String mediaPath = "content://media/external/audio/media/1234";

    Uri audioUrl = Uri.parse(mediaPath);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, audioUrl);
    mp.start();
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

```
String mediaPath = "content://media/external/audio/media/1234";

MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(context,Uri.parse(mediaPath));
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```